# static only config for nginx?

Tags: web-server, configuration, nginx

I was trying to get a static only config for nginx working with try_files but was running into some issues. The following is what I have working right now (but does not deal with directories, showing index etc.) I would like to see if I can get a version with try_files working...

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.com;
    rewrite ^ http://www.foo.com$uri permanent;
  }

  # the server directive is nginx's virtual host directive.
  server {
    # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
    listen 80;

    # Set the charset
    charset utf-8;

    # Set the max size for file uploads to 10Mb
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    # sets the domain[s] that this vhost server requests for
    server_name www.foo.com; 

    # doc root
    root /var/www/foo.com;

    # vhost specific access log
    access_log  /var/log/nginx_access.log  main;


    # Set image format types to expire in a very long time
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    # Set css and js to expire in a very long time
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location /blog {
     rewrite ^ http://blog.foo.com permanent; 
    }

    # Catchall for everything else
    location / {
      root /var/www/foo.com;
      access_log off;

      index index.html index.shtml;
      expires 1d;

      #try_files $uri $uri/;

      if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
      }
    }

    location ~* ^/(pkg|rpms)/ {
      autoindex on;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule#try_files:

> In the event that no file is found, and internal redirect to the last parameter is invoked.

Without a URI at the end of the `try_files`, it won't work right.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I ended up putting a /404.html at the end of the try_files directive and it works.